# what are the differences between Widevine HDCP levels (v1,v2,v2.2) & Widevine Security levels?

Tags: android, drm, widevine, hdcp

How does it effect android mobile phones DRM contents streaming. When i check DRMinfo in android devices some phones shows HDCP level unprotected. Some shows HDCP level Disconnected.what is the difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

The wide vine security levels refer to different type of security depending on the implementation on the device:

- Level 1 means that the Widevine client, the decryption and the video processing  is tied to a hardware security in the device, e.g. TEE, and that there is a secure media path, from receipt to display. Most Android phones and tablets support this.
- Level 3 is software security SDK based and no secure media path exists. This is used where not tied to HW, e.g. TEE, exists or is available for the DRM application to use. Browsers typically support this.
- Level 2 is a mix where the Widevine cryptography is HW tied but the video processing is not - in practice this is not commonly used.

The HDCP numbers are versions not levels - the newer versions and more secure as the technology evolves to address known attacks.